# Not able to run emulator in Android Studio due to error

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, android-emulator, emulation

**I get the following error whenever I try to run the emulator in android studio.
I am using the latest version of android studio.**

WARNING | unexpected system image feature string, emulator might not function correctly, please try updating the emulator. init: Could not find wglGetExtensionsString! arbFound 0 listarbNull/empty 1 0 extFound 0 extNull/empty 1 0 remote 0 OpenGL Core Profile not supported. ERROR | Could not find GLES 2.x config! ERROR | Failed to obtain GLES 2.x extensions string! ERROR | Could not initialize emulated framebuffer ERROR | Failed to open /qemu.conf, err: 2 INFO | added library vulkan-1.dll HAX is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode. INFO | Started GRPC server at 127.0.0.1:8554, security: Local INFO | Advertising in: C:\Users\Ayush Singh\AppData\Local\Temp\avd\running\pid_14224.ini ERROR | OpenGLES emulation failed to initialize. Please consider the following troubleshooting steps: 1. Make sure your GPU drivers are up to date. 2. Erase and re-download the emulator ($ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/emulator). 3. Try software rendering: Go to Extended Controls > Settings > Advanced tab and change "OpenGL ES renderer (requires restart)" to "Swiftshader". Or, run emulator from command line with "-gpu swiftshader_indirect". 4. Please file an issue to https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:192727 and provide your complete CPU/GPU info plus OS and display setup. ERROR | crashhandler_die: fatal: OpenGLES emulation failed to initialize. Please consider the following troubleshooting steps: 1. Make sure your GPU drivers are up to date. 2. Erase and re-download the emulator ($ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/emulator). 3. Try software rendering: Go to Extended Controls > Settings > Advanced tab and change "OpenGL ES renderer (requires restart)" to "Swiftshader". Or, run emulator from command line with "-gpu swiftshader_indirect". 4. Please file an issue to https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:192727 and provide your complete CPU/GPU info plus OS and display setup. INFO | Android emulator version 31.2.10.0 (build_id 8420304) (CL:N/A)

Comment: Try software rendering: Go to Extended Controls > Settings > Advanced tab and change "OpenGL ES renderer (requires restart)" to "Swiftshader"

Comment: This method worked but it is responding very slowly.

Comment: Software rendering is of course slower than hardware rendering. But this suggests that the problem was recognized. That you have a conflict between the emulator and video card drivers. You can try to update them.